# How I can extract year from a date in sql and use it in where clause

Tags: sql, date, hive, where-clause

I have a date column in a table which is named `released_date` and the format of its data is for example: `01-Jan-1995`. I want to have just the years which are greater than `1997`. Does anybody know how I can write such query?

Comment: Hello @Sahar to SO. You can share your attempts with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the date is in dd-MMM-yyyy format, you can use regexp_extract:

```
select regexp_extract (released_date, '(\\d{4})$',1) as year
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE year(released_date) > 1997
```

Comment: actually i should write a query:   Find all rows (or lines) with rating greater than 3 for movies in years after 1997 (1998, 1999, …) and output the movie name and the average rating. about the detail i should say we have two table that movieid is common in both of them. movie_name column and released_date are in the first table(film.u_item) and rating column is in the second table (film.u_data)

Comment: select movieid, movie_name, avg(rating),
     year(*) from (select year(released_date) as year where year > 1997)
    from film.u_item a join film.u_data b
     on a.movieid = b.movieid
     where rating > 3
    group by a.movieid, movie_name;